# what is the equivalence of tf.one_hot in tensorflow 2.0.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

```
 train_label = tf.keras.backend.one_hot(train_label,3)
 train_label = tf.one_hot(train_label,3)
```

give the following error in tensorflow 2.0.0

```
InternalError: Could not find valid device for node.
```

Node: {{node OneHot}}

Comment: It doesn't appear to be a problem with [tf.one_hot](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/one_hot)

Comment: Please provide more (all) of the code leading to this error

Answer (score 3):

`train_label` should be a `INT` type data. for example:

```
train_label = [1, 2 ,3]
train_label = tf.one_hot(train_label,3) // work

train_label = [1., 2., 3.]
train_label = tf.one_hot(train_label,3) // InternalError: Could not find valid device for node.
```